# Ubuntu Terminal command: Show what time after X seconds?

Tags: date, time, while-loop, sleep, gnome-terminal

I need to know if there is a command where I can show what time it will be after X seconds.

In my case: I often need to set "sleep (seconds)"; in terminal before and between other following commands (seperated by ;) and it would be greatfull to see what time it will be after (seconds).

I know this command: date -d@(seconds) -u +%H:%M:%S. But this only show me the duration, so its a conversion. That is a compromise but not exactly what I need.

I hope I explained it understandable and someone can help me^^

Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a sum to current timestamp (in second) with the coming sleep delay (in seconds too) with `$((a + b))`.

Then, your initial command transforms to:

```bash
date -d@$((timestamp + 10)) -u +%H:%M:%S
```

The final command can look like:

```bash
date -d@$((`date +%s` + 60)) -u +%H:%M:%S
```

EDIT: As per the OP comment bellow this answer, "Why do I have to add 3600 for not having a timestamp in the past?"

This is due to the local of your system. Indeed, in one part of the command you get the total elapsed seconds from 1970 ... regarding your local, while on the other part, you print the timestamp in reference to UTC.

As your local may be UTC+1 this explains why you have to add one more extra hour (3600 seconds).

You can stick to your system's local with:

```bash
date -d@$((`date +%s` + 60)) +%H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. I tried it out but it shows me a timestamp what is already past. (exactly 1 hour if I type 0). I show you what I mean:
user@ubuntu:~$ date
Mi 11. Jan 11:52:20 CET 2023

user@ubuntu:~$ date -d@$((`date +%s` + 1800)) -u +%H:%M:%S
11:22:28

user@ubuntu:~$ date -d@$((`date +%s` + 0)) -u +%H:%M:%S
10:52:41
The current timestamp of 11:52 is correct.

update: If I use date -d@$((`date +%s` + 3600 + 1800)) -u +%H:%M:%S, it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! But I am curious, maybe you can say me why I need to put +3600 to get the correct time?

Comment: @STAIGlobalBlockchain I updated the answer to give you some more clues regarding this behavior. Keep in mind to mark answers which answer your question as approved and enjoy your days on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer shown here is quite fragile, parsing a date is especially prone to errors arounds daylight saving time adjustments, but apparently it even has problems with timezones (as the poster there says to add 3600).

Luckily, `date` has built-in capability of doing simple arithmetics on dates. E.g. to see the timestamp in 30 seconds from now:

```
date -d '+30 seconds'
```

It understands words like `tomorrow`, `years`, `days`, `hours` etc. and you can cascade additions and subtractions, so it's pretty simple and intuitive to use. You can even start from a specific timestamp and do arithmetics from there (rather than from the default *now*), e.g.

```
date -d '2024/01/01 - 1 day'
```

and so on.

The output format can be specified in a parameter starting with `+`, as usual.